# Javascript regular expression global replace on strings with variables

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to add soft hyphens to break up long urls and other strings in some plain text.

```
function breakLines(str, num){
    if(typeof num == 'undefined' || num == null){ num = 15;}
    regex = new RegExp('(\S{'+num+'})(\S{'+num+'})','g');
    return str.replace(regex, '$1&shy;$2');
}
```

It works if I use the slash notation for the replace but this function above doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't escape the \ next the the '\S's. Works fine now.